# How do I plot a row of a data frame against vector values as a curve?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, all values are numeric, I am interested in plotting all the values of the second row against a vector of the same length.

```
vector = seq(400, 2498, 2)
```

this vector is length 1050. This is the same length of the row.
I want to plot this row against the values of the vector and join the dots of the plot.

Comment: `plot(vector, unlist(your_data[2, ]), type = "l")`. Though if you have all numeric data and frequently want to work with rows rather than columns, you might want to use a `matrix` rather than a `data.frame`

Comment: Can you please calrify what you want? I read it as you want to have the values of one row as your x values and the values of the other row as your y values. Is this correct?

Comment: @MacOS apologizes, I want vector on the x axis, and I want the values of the row on the y axis

Comment: @GregorThomas This has helped me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to my question, the following should work.

```
vector = seq(400, 2498, 2)

# A dummy data frame with two rows.
my.df <- as.data.frame(t(
                         data.frame(values = runif(1050),
                                    other.values = runif(1050))))

plot(x = vector,
     y = my.df[1, ]) # we select row one here. Choose the row number you want.
```

HTH!